# Tomcat Error Too Many open files

Tags: tomcat

I want to know the exact problem of Too many files opened error. I went through google for solution but i could not get why this problem happens and how to solve the problem. is that some thing about ulimit value ?

---

stack error : SEVERE: Socket accept failed java.net.SocketException: Too many open files at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398) at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530) at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServer‌​SocketFactory.java:61) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:352) –  user2883376 yesterday

Linux server and this is my last update in the code to get messages based on language. ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml"); name = context.getMessage(key, null, locale); return name;

Any suggestions on this error ?

Comment: It looks like problem with ulimit. Please put more details, like OS and error message. Is there any stack error?

Comment: The OS may restrict the number of files a process can have open. Maybe you did not close files after you are done with them?

Comment: stack error : SEVERE: Socket accept failed
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:352)

Comment: Linux server and this is my last update in the code to get messages based on language. ApplicationContext context  = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml");
  name = context.getMessage(key, null, locale);
  return name;

Answer (score 4):

The problem is almost certainly that you are leaking file handles somewhere in your code. I have Tomcats that stay up for months at a time without encountering this.

Comment: How to identify the file leaking. As i am using hibernate for ORM. is that about JDBC connections ? or reading the properties file ?

Answer (score -2):

Although if "ulimit" is raised at some point down the line tomcat stops causing same error.

So in order to **avoid** this you can check list of open files for the application user on Linux using command "lsof -u username" or simply "lsof" and see if code related files are open ( eg..properties files ) if so kill those specific files using  # kill -9 `lsof -t -u username`  command for that specific tomcat user.

You need to **fix your code** to load those files writing simply in a **static block** of your classes. So that only one file loads even if multiple hits are made by any number of users.

Now you can re check after deploying new changes with the same `lsof` command and see. Only one file will be seen. This will ***permanently fix your issue*** without raising the ulimit each time.